# Why do Python regex spans extend one place past the actual match?

Tags: python, regex

Looking at the spans returned from my regex matches, I noticed that they always return one past the actual match; e.g. in the example at [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/regex.html)

```
>>> print(p.match('::: message'))
None
>>> m = p.search('::: message'); print(m)  
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x...>
>>> m.group()
'message'
>>> m.span()
(4, 11)
```

The resulting span in the example is `(4, 11)` vs. the actual location `(4, 10)`. This causes some trouble for me as the left-hand and right-hand boundaries have different meanings and I need to compare the relative positions of the spans.

Is there a good reason for this or can I go ahead and modify the spans to my liking by subtracting one from the right boundary?

Comment: this answer should your understanding http://stackoverflow.com/a/509297/659346

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in Python, slicing and ranges never the end value is always exclusive, and `'::: message'[4:11]` reflects the actual matched text:

```
>>> '::: message'[4:11]
'message'
```

Thus, you can use the `MatchObject.span()` results to slice the matched text from the original string:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '::: message'
>>> match = p.search(s)
>>> match.span()
(4, 11)
>>> s[slice(*match.span())]
'message'
```

Comment: I see so the designers wanted a way to slice nothing wile still providing indexes.  I.e. they wanted 'message'[x:x] to return empty.

Comment: @Colin: exactly; also see [Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/509211) for some helpful diagrams.